# How to get topic list from ROSBridge?

Tags: ros, rosbridge, rostopic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've beem unsing ROSBridge 2.0 to communicate with ros, and i'm trying to get the topic list using the following JSON message:
{
"op": "call_service",
"service": "/rosapi/topics"
}
but i get an error on ros with the following text : "call_service InvalidServiceException: Service /rosapi/topics does not exist".

I can call services from rosservice but not from rossrv...

What am i doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168241/how-to-get-topic-list-from-rosbridge?/) by [Sky---](https://answers.ros.org/users/18261/sky---/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-05-22**:
How did you start the rosbridge? did you rosrun or roslaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already fixed it.

The problem was that i did not knew that the rosapi node had to be started. After i started the node (rosrun rosapi rosapi) it worked like a charm...

Thanks anyways.

---

Originally posted by [Sky---](https://answers.ros.org/users/18261/sky---/) with karma: 46 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2